# Execute jQuery function after loop in ember template finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

The app I'm developing uses `ember.js` with bootstrap and the problem I'm having is calling the jQuery functions **AFTER** the ember template has **FULLY** finished rendering (including loops).

The specific problem I want to solve is how to call the bootstrap jQuery functions after an `{{#each}}` loop in my template has finished.

I have used `didInserElement()` and `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent)`, but they don't solve my problem with the loop.

I am creating a list of collapsible 'widget-boxes' inside an `{{#each}}` loop in my template, and wish to call the bootstrap jQuery function `(widget_boxes())` after its finished looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around this problem I used the 'accordion' boostrap widget (instead of a 'widget-box'). This allowed me to target the correct accordion panel within the list that the {{#each}} created.

```
<div id="accordion" class="accordion-style1 panel-group">
{{#each item in list}}
    . . . accordion toggle
    . . . accordion panel
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need to call `widget_boxes` on the whole list or on every element of the list. If it's on every element, you could add a separate view for every item inside `each` loop and run your widget function in its `didInsertElement` method.

Comment: I've tried that alright, but it renders very slow. And i only need to call the jQuery function once at the end of the loop, because it works when i call it manually from the browser console. Thanks though.